# How to join jsp and controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I want to write a simple web application with Java and Spring. So I have setting the app but I have soma problem. So this is the

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVCApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this is the springmvcapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcapp.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is the code in the Index.jsp to call another page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
....
....
....
<form action="registrazione.html">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" onclick="submit">Registrazione</button>
</form>
```

This is the RegistrazioneController.java

```
package com.springmvcapp.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/RegistrazioneController")
public class RegistrazioneController extends MultiActionController{


    public ModelAndView registrazione(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("registrazione");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendDati")
    public String getDataFromForum(@RequestParam String nome){
        System.out.println("pippo");
        return nome;
    }

    public String getViewName() throws Exception {
        return "registrazione";
    }

    public String getPageName() throws Exception {
        return "registrazione";
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem when I try to click and open the registrazone.jsp

In addition to I want know if the method to join jsp and controller that I have used is correct or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add @RequestMapping in your controller like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registrazione")
public ModelAndView registrazione(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("registrazione");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: I have insert @RequestMapping("/registrazione") code on name of Controllare. and it works. But it's correct my solution or not?

Comment: It depends on how your url is configured. Use it at controller level if its the base url, else do it at method level. Please accept it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you tell the dispatcher where your spring context is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>               
            classpath:springmvcapp-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```